# reference error: grecaptcha is undefined in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, recaptcha

I have two captcha on same form. One on submit and other on a modal which will open after form submit. So I render it after reading many answer from here. Now it is working fine with *mozilla* but giving reference error in chrome.

My google api is:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Then my code renders this in java script:

```
$('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
        widgetId = grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'My-SITE-KEY'});
});
```

My html read like this

```
<div id="user_recaptcha" class="reCaptcha">
    <div id="e_Captcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY; ?>" data-callback="recaptchaCallbackEvent"></div>
</div>
```

I declare `widgetId` at the top of my js.

Comment: Can u share some more of ur code so that I can get a better picture about it. Please add the html too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recaptcha has a onload callback that will run once recaptcha is loaded. Place your code inside that callback function.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

```
//call this function in your js
function onloadCallback() {
    $('.g-recaptcha').each(function(index, el) {
        widgetId = grecaptcha.render(el, {'sitekey' : 'My-SITE-KEY'});
    });
}

//load this script before your js is loading
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"></script>
//your html is absolutely fine.
```

Comment: better late than never. Thanks mate. you saved me.